# Foreground or background service for geo location tracking

Tags: android

In order to create a location tracking system (based on fusedlocationprovider) which has to track the location of a person for a specific period of time.

At specific intervals, the location needs to be broadcast and the service should not be killed even if the application is closed.

Should I be using a foreground or background service or a combination of both and an explanation would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get location for specific interval of time you can use work manager for that but, you want to use service only which you need not to be killed then you should use foreground service according to googles guide line if the service without foreground notification it will be stop when app get killed.

https://developer.android.com/guide/background/

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#11